# MarkLogic Data Hub document metadata added by steps

Tags: metadata, marklogic, document, marklogic-dhf, hub

According to the documentation:

[Document metadata added by steps](https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.6/flows/about-flows.html)

> For every content object outputted by a Data Hub step, regardless of the step type, Data Hub will add the following document metadata keys and values to the document wrapped by the content object:

> - `datahubCreatedOn` = the date and time at which the document is written
> - `datahubCreatedBy` = the MarkLogic user used to run the step
> - `datahubCreatedInFlow` = the name of the flow containing the step being run
> - `datahubCreatedByStep` = the name of the step being run
> - `datahubCreatedByJob` = the ID of the job being run; this will contain the job ID of every flow run on the step, with multiple values being space-delimited

Is there any possibility to add some extra metadata keys and values to the document?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add additional static values in your headers options or use one of these keywords to dynamically add values.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "sources": [{
            "name": "loadCustomersJSON"
        }],
        "createdOn": "datahubCreatedOn",
        "createdBy": "datahubCreatedBy"
    }
}
```

You can also dynamically add values by using an interceptor
(See: https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.6/flows/about-interceptors-custom-hooks.html) or updating the header value in a custom step if you are already using one (See:https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.6/modules/editing-custom-step-module.html

Comment: Since they mentioned the metadata keys datahubCreatedOn, etc. I think they want to change the document metadata, which can be done by setting content.context.metadata as described in the "Required Inputs" section of "Editing a Custom Step Module". (https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.6/modules/editing-custom-step-module.html)

Comment: Ok, Andrew, thanks for your answer!